# Monitoring ng test runs from other eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, testng

I am developing an eclipse plugin that shows the user links to test logs. In the current implementation we register a jUnit run listener that updates the view whenever a suite has been run and this works fine, problem is that the test framework now also support TestNG and we will need the equivalent functionality from the TestNG plugin if the user runs a TestNG testcase.

I found this feature request http://jira.opensymphony.com/browse/TESTNG-313 which suggests that the functionality I am looking for is there to use, at least that´s how I interpret it. Anyway, I can´t seem to get it to work. I try to create and define different objects in the view setup that should listen for ng-runs and calls to for example onFinish() but I have not found a way to "register" the listening class the way you are if you are defining a regular listener from the suite.xml or code. The TestNG class seems to be a singleton but only for every testrun, not for monitoring the plugin for whenever a suite is run. The TestNGPlugin class does not seem to have appropriate methods. Just implementing a TestListenerAdapter or ITestListener interface as a private class does not do the trick.

Does anyone know which is the most appropriate class or interface to implement for this and if needed, how they should be registered?

Btw I am using Eclipse 3.7.0 and TestNG 6.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way around the problem, probably a better solution in the end. I monitor the org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugPlugin for any launch of any kind and do the update depending on that. This little piece of code made it work.

```
    ILaunchesListener2 runListener = new ILaunchesListener2() {
                @Override
                public void launchesAdded(ILaunch[] arg0) {
                }
                @Override
                public void launchesChanged(ILaunch[] arg0) {       
                }
                @Override
                public void launchesRemoved(ILaunch[] arg0) {
                }

                @Override
                public void launchesTerminated(ILaunch[] arg0) {
                    Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                            updateTestRunList();
                            viewer.setInput(testRuns);
                            viewer.refresh();
                        }
                    });

                }
            };
            DebugPlugin.getDefault().getLaunchManager().addLaunchListener(runListener);
```